# Robocopy no me detecta bien el texto que introduzco con ConfigParser

Tags: python

Tengo un software GUI que permite mover archivos por extensiones y estoy usando Robocopy y Configparser. Las extensiones elegidas por el usuario se almacenan en:

```
Files_1_Extensions_Read = parser.get("Extensions", "Search_1")
```

Si añado manualmente las extensiones en el código funciona y puedo añadir varias seguidas (ejemplo: "*mp4", "*avi" etc) mi problema ocurre cuando usando la GUI introduzco una lista de extensiones como la mencionada anteriormente. Robocopy no detecta las extensiones correctamente y no copia nada. Esta es la llamada que estoy utilizando:

```
call(["robocopy",src_1,dst_1,"/S",Files_1_Extensions_Read])
```

Lo curioso es que en la consola de sublimetext cuando coloco las extensiones a través de GUI sale así:

[Imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws5bP.png)

Y cuando los coloco directamente en el código me sale así:

[Imagen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqrMw.png)

Es como si robocopy no pudiera leer correctamente el texto y lo tomara como si no hubiera nada.

Ya he intentado usar literal_eval() solo para descartar y sigue sin funcionar.

Mi intención es no hacer publicidad de mi software, así que no sé si puedo poner mi repositorio en GitHub con todo el código de mi programa (+3.000 líneas) por si alguien quiere ayudarme con este problema y necesita ver el código fuente. Si algún moderador me lo permite, lo pondré.

Comment: Lo siento no conozco mucho del modulo que dices, la variable `Files_1_Extensions_Read` es la que contiene las extensiones?

Comment: Si, las extensiones son almacenadas en Files_1_Extensions_Read . La verdad tengo 2 días con este problema y no encuentro solución.

Comment: prueba haciendo un `type(Files_1_Extensions_Read )` para verificar el tipo de dato

Comment: Arroja TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not type.

Comment: °-°, ni idea de por que pasa eso, si todos los datos son *String* prueba haciendo `call(["robocopy",f"{src_1,dst_1}","/S",f"{Files_1_Extensions_Read}"])`

Comment: Me sale ERROR: no se especifico el directorio de destino. Por lo que veo, tampoco funciona con las f-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de separar cada extensión como un elemento de la lista, por ejemplo si quiero copiar archivos `.bmp` y `.pptx` desde *ORIGEN* hasta *DESTINO*:

```
from subprocess import call
ORIGEN = 'C:\\go'
DESTINO = 'C:\\deep'
call(["robocopy", ORIGEN,DESTINO,"/S","*.bmp","*.pptx"])
```

Suponiendo que de `configparser` obtienes una lista de extensiones como string (eso o numeros jajá) con las extensiones separadas por un espacio(en caso de ser un formato  mas complejo siempre puedes confiar en bigMama osea..RegEx...) como a continuación:

```
from subprocess import call
ORIGEN = 'C:\\go'
DESTINO = 'C:\\deep'
listaEx="*mp4 *mp3 *docx *bmp" #Lista extensiones

listaEx = listaEx.split(" ") 

callInfo = ["robocopy", ORIGEN, DESTINO,"/S"] 

callInfo.extend(listaEx) 
#Nota: el motivo porque saque el argumento del call() fue porque no se puede iterar dentro de esta con extend

call(callInfo) #that's all
```

En tu codigo el agregar `Files_1_Extensions_Read` al final es lo mismo que agregar un string, call no sabra que hacer con esto (mejor dicho, robocopy no sabrá que hacer, podrias agregar un LOG:archivolog al final para ver que es lo que hace robocopy de fondo)

Comment: Funciono! te lo agradezco mucho. Efectivamente, el problema era que no estaba convirtiendo cada extensión en un elemento de la lista y por eso RoboCopy no sabia que hacer.